# How to insert a Boolean variable into a JSON string in C#

Tags: c#, json, string

Suppose I have the following:

```
var b = true;
var f = "{ \"templateName\": \"name\", \"Active\": \"" +b + "\"}";
```

That b value does not work for me :( , I tried different scenario's with no luck.

Comment: You should use a JSON library.

Comment: How ? my API accept calls in that format !

Comment: Use [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serialize an _object_.  Never build your own JSON string, its a _horrible_ idea.

Comment: ... you are missing a quotation mark to properly concatenate your string. `"{ \"templateName\": \"name\", \"Active\": \" " +b + "\"}";`

Comment: _does not work for me_ isn't much of a problem description. But as other stated, use JSON.Net. Don't try and create your own JSON by string concatenation. It'll drive you nuts.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work for me"? If you mean that it does not show as a Boolean value in JavaScript, well, no, it wouldn't. You're sending it as a string (you've surrounded it in quotes). Also, the default string representation of a Boolean in .NET is "True" or "False". Note the case.

Comment: To have it as a boolean it should be `"{ \"templateName\": \"name\", \"Active\": " + b + "}"`. But yeah, you need a library

Comment: @Dumisani: Actually that wouldn't work because it would insert `True` instead of `true`. Which, again, is a reason to use a library.

Comment: yeah that's a valid point

Comment: Thank you guys, I will check how I can make it work with JSON and get back to you. The thing is I am making a DLL library in c# then working with that library in JSCRIPT. I will test few things.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way of doing this is to work with objects directly.  Then you can serialize to whatever format you want (if you want JSON, [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is what you should use).

For instance, you should have a class that looks *something* like this:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string TemplateName { get; set; }
}
```

This is a class that represents your JSON object, but instead of modifying strings and dealing with that headache, we just deal with *objects*.

In your code you can instantiate and/or modify an instance of that object:

```
var testObj = new TestClass()
{
    Active = true,
    TemplateName = "SomeName"
};

//changed my mind, I want Active to be false now
testObj.Active = false;
```

Then with the power of JSON.NET you can *serialize* this object into JSON:

```
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testObj);
```

Comment: Say I use stringfy() in JScript , should I serialize again before I send my POST request ?

Comment: Work with objects until you transmit, then you serialize.

Comment: Here is my issue,in my JScript code I get a Template using GET from my c# dll. That returns a json string , then in JScript , I do JSON.Parse on my response to convert it to an object........then I change few values in that object in Jscript , then I send the new one to my API. The only way that it works now is to send it as "{ \"templateName\": \"name\", \"Active\": \"X\"}";

Comment: @fazlook1 How does the JSON get from your "c# dll" to your "JScript"?

Comment: I use TestComplete software. So I add the library as a reference and use DotNET library to call my methods.

Comment: Here is my call in C#: HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                HttpContent content = response.Content;
                result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }

Comment: So basically if I want to follow your TestClass, that will be in my C# code and not in JScript. I need to decide what to send from Jscript and play with it in C#. The only method I am aware of in JScript is Stringfy()

Comment: I think I have an idea. I am currently deserializing in C#, if I send my JScript JSON object, I will Serialize instead :) let me try.

Comment: @fazlook1 if you want your javascript to modify the objects then send your javascript json.  If you want your C# to modify it _before_ your javascript gets it, then deserialize into an object, modify it, then serialize it and send it to your javascript

Comment: Not sure what I am doing wrong, the returned results from GET are like this { "Active" : true, TemplateName : "dsdsdsd" }.....this is json string. I am serializing it then send it in my PUT request but it is not working.